# How do I resolve this ctypes install error? (PyCharm CE)

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, ctypes

I am trying to add ctypes to my python interpreter but am getting an error I do not know how to resolve. How do I fix this error? I am using windows 10, and pycharm CE edition 2019.3.2. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctypes` in PyPI is ancient. Modern versions of Python have it built in, with no need to install anything.